# Missing 'biblatex' package

Tags: biblatex, biber

I'm attempting to create a bibliography using biber, via Tex Live (installed on a Linux Mint 11 machine).

My source .bib file is:

```
@article{simon06,
  author = {Simon, E. and Flaschker, N. and Schadewaldt, P. and Langenbeck, U. and Wendel, U.},
  title = {Variant maple syrup urine disease (MSUD)--the entire spectrum},
  year = 2006,
  journal = {Journal of inherited metabolic disease},
  volume = 29,
  number = 6,
  pages = {716--24},
  pmid = 17063375,
  doi = {10.1007/s10545-006-0276-1},
  keywords = {}
}
```

My pmid.tex file is:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear-icomp,
    sortlocale=de_DE,
    natbib=true,
    url=false, 
    doi=true,
    eprint=false
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{pmid.bib}

\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
}

%% ##############################
\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet~\citep{simon06}.
    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum~\citet{simon06}.
    \printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

My sequence is:

```
pdflatex, biber, pdflatex
```

After running biber pmid, the resulting pmid.bbl file contains an error:

```
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{ver@biblatex.sty}
  {\@latex@error
     {Missing 'biblatex' package}
     {The bibliography requires the 'biblatex' package.}
      \aftergroup\endinput}
  {}
\endgroup
```

biblatex is apparently not installed.   I tried issuing tlmgr install biblatex, received no errors, but am continuing to get the 'missing biblatex' error.

Any help and/or guidance appreciated.

Comment: That's not an error in the `.bbl` file, it's a safety check. The error is only issued if you try to use the `.bbl` with a `.tex` file that does not load `biblatex`. Did you actually get an error when using the file?

Comment: Don't kill me -- I just started looking at latex a couple days ago. I forgot to run pdflatex a second time.  Did that just now and the reference shows up in the PDF.

Comment: Perhaps this is a separate question but is it allowable to only generate a bibliography?  The working example tex file I have includes more than just bibliography.

Comment: `\begin{document}\nocite{*}\printbibliography\end{document}` plus a suitable preamble

Comment: This works perfectly, though I'm not familiar with the preamble code.

Comment: The preamble, in LaTeX parlance, is the stuff between `\documentclass{...}` and `\begin{document}`. A suitable preamble, in the case at hand, would (at a minimum!) instruct LaTeX to load `biblatex`, specify any particular bibliography styles, and specify one or more `.bib` bibliography database files containing the entries of interest to you.

Answer (score 14):

The construction

```
\@ifundefined{ver@biblatex.sty}
  {\@latex@error
     {Missing 'biblatex' package}
     {The bibliography requires the 'biblatex' package.}
      \aftergroup\endinput}
  {}
```

is a test with two branches, which checks if `biblatex` is loaded. If it is, then `\ver@biblatex.sty` is defined and nothing happens. If it is *not* defined, the `.tex` file which read the `.bbl` file did not load `biblatex`. In that case an error is raised. Thus this is a safety precaution, not an error.

Comment: It is somewhat inconvenient when the tex file does not have to be the one initiating the biblatex process: do you know if there is a way to suppress this behaviour ?

Comment: @user22744 I'm not sure I follow: the `.bbl` has to have ben generated by a TeX file that used `biblatex`

Comment: I agree with that ! What I mean is that it is cumbersome to have to hit enter each time you compile because of that "security". In my case, for instance (which is the one I'm the most interested in ;-) ), this happens systematically after biber did its job : each new iteration of pdflatex leads to "LaTeX Error: Missing 'biblatex' package" and I have to hit enter for the process to keep going. I find that annoying (I'll live, though, but that was not a issue with bibtex, for instance).

Comment: @user22744 That's not normal: you have something odd going on - really needs an independent question

Comment: OK, thanks a lot for your answers !! I'll post a question, then - need time to produce a MWE, though, which I don't have right now.